# Functions defined on nonmeasurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E$ be nonmeasurable and define 
$$f=\begin{cases}0,\,x\in E\\\frac1{x}\quad\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ and $$g=\begin{cases}0\quad\text{otherwise}\\\dfrac1{x},\,\,x\in E\end{cases}$$

Then, is $f$ measurable and $g$ non measurable? I think both are nonmeasurable, because, the inverse image of a measurable set, $\{0\}$ is nonmeasurable in both cases. Any hints. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: @Bernard please check now. edited the post

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, since $\{0\}$ is closed, $E = f^{-1} (0)$ would be measurable. Since $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ is open, $g^{-1} (\mathbb{R}-\{0\}) = E$ would be measurable.